# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in ORACLE SQL unexpected parenthesis issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am trying to execute an SQL query to solve this problem:**Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.
Sample Input:
Let's say that CITY only has four entries:
DEF, ABC, PQRS and WXY
Sample Output:
ABC 3
PQRS 4

**

I was able to solve this challenge using MySQL.However I am facing error while trying to solve the same in Oracle ,albeit with minor changes.Here is what exactly I am trying with :

```
(SELECT CITY ,length(CITY)
FROM STATION
ORDER BY length(CITY) ASC ,CITY FETCH FIRST 1 ROW)
UNION ALL
(SELECT CITY ,length(CITY)
FROM STATION
ORDER BY length(CITY) DESC ,CITY FETCH FIRST 1 ROW);
```

I get the error :

```
ORDER BY length(CITY) ASC ,CITY FETCH FIRST 1 ROW) 
* 
ERROR at line 3: 
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

I am unable to figure out the error here, given that I was able to solve it in an almost similar fashion in MySQL. Can someone please point out my mistake here?

Comment: Oracle 11g doesn't support `FETCH FIRST`, so that might be one problem.

Comment: I just added that as a tag,I am executing this code in Hackerrank.I do believe that they are version agnostic.Again,can you tell me if using rownum would be better.I tried with rownum too but received the same error.

Comment: The Oracle parser often says "missing parenthesis" to indicate that it encountered something unexpected.  The point where it indicates the error - in this case the `ORDER BY`- is often syntactically invalid.  One of the existing answers explains why `ORDER BY` is not allowed in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

**You Cannot Use ORDER BY in the Subquery Associated with the UNION, UNION ALL, MINUS or INTERSECT Operators**

You have an `ORDER BY` used in both subqueries of the `UNION ALL` which is not permitted (see here, https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries004.htm#SQLRF52341).

I would just throw these subqueries (aka query blocks) in to common table expressions and perform your work there.

The common table expression permits the use of:

-order by

-row limiting clause

I used the instructional HR schema below.

In an 11G environment, as Gordon Linoff et al have stated, row limiting clauses did not exist. You would do something like this:

```
WITH stations AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY length(city), city) rn,
        length(city)  city_length,
        city
    FROM
        locations
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    stations
WHERE
    rn <= 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    *
FROM
    stations
WHERE
    rn >= (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM stations)
ORDER BY
    1
```

In a post-11G environment, you would leverage the row limiting clause features:

```
WITH stations_desc AS (
    SELECT
        length(city),
        city
    FROM
        locations stations
    ORDER BY
        length(city) DESC,
        city
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
), stations_asc AS (
    SELECT
        length(city),
        city
    FROM
        locations stations
    ORDER BY
        length(city) ASC,
        city
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    stations_asc
UNION ALL
SELECT
    *
FROM
    stations_desc;


LENGTH(CITY)    CITY
-----------------------
 4              Bern
19              South San Francisco
```

This will produce the results you are trying to achieve.

---

BTW, the syntax for the row limiting clause is as follows in Oracle 12c:

```
[ OFFSET offset { ROW | ROWS } ]
[ FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } [ { rowcount | percent PERCENT } ]
    { ROW | ROWS } { ONLY | WITH TIES } ]
```

You omitted the segment, `{ ONLY | WITH TIES } ]`

Comment: An `order by` **is** allowed but then you need to put each query between parentheses (which are usually useless for a UNION query): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0d3d3603e3de20555393a7ff7ff56c51

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you. I see that it does work in sql fiddle. When I execute your sql in https://livesql.oracle.com/ (19c), it throws this error:  `ORA-20001: Query must begin with SELECT or WITH`

Comment: Well that's a limitation of that strange web interface

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
FETCH first 1 rows only;
```

or

```
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

As has been mention this syntax isn't available in 11g